# phar obtain command line arguments

Tags: php, phar

I am looking into phar to wrap up an executable 
I can find no way to pass arguments and access them 
For example

```
php file.phar x y z
```

Is this possible - if so please point me in the right direction

Many thanks

Comment: The right direction: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: I was aware of this but was struggling to get the arguments into my phar

Comment: If your phar is created correctly then there is nothing to change in the PHP code (assuming the index script of the phar file already handles the command line arguments.)

Comment: Yes that was the key assuming the index script of the phar file already handles the command line arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated  by axiac all that is needed is to handle the arguments in the index.php file

Answer (score 0):

for example if you run `php test.phar arg1`, you can access your `arg1` argument in your php file by `$_SERVER['argv'][1]`;

for more information checkout [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)